# Space in batch commands (del and taskkill)

Tags: batch

I have a problem using `del` and `taskkill`.

```
del D:\New Folder.exe
```

I tried changing the code to this:

```
del D:\"New Folder.exe"
```

That didn't work

So I tried this:

```
del "D:\New Folder.exe"
```

Still not working. But *this* is working:

```
del "D:\New Folder"
```

The problem is I must remove the `.exe` to make this work.

And I have this problem too:

```
taskkill /F/IM New Folder.exe
```

Comment: Do you get error messages from any of those commands?  Do you have a file or folder called `New Folder.exe` on your `D:` drive?  Also, please ask any unrelated questions you have in a separate question here on StackExchange.

Comment: hi that problem has been fixed tnx i will post them on there i didnot know .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `del "D:\New Folder.exe"` should work just fine...I've tested it just now multiple times.  If it isn't working then you need to post the error code/message you are getting.

Same goes for your `taskkill` command, and your access denied in the `attrib` command.

The last two could possibly be related to UAC (user account control) issues, but we won't know if you don't post the actual error.  Make sure you are running the batch file from an Administrative level command prompt.

Oh, and update your questions tags with more than just `batch` if you would.  Include the specific OS at a minimum.

Comment: HI TNX   ITS WORKING NOW(NOT YET TEST THE TASKKILL BUT I THINK THAT WILL WORK TO) ABOUT ATTRIB even when i use Administrative level i have the same problem i test that on win 7 and win xp (vmware)but its not working perhaps its because some of that file i am trying to unhide them are visble or not exist!

Comment: You would need to post the existing attribs of the file along with whatever error code you are getting.

Comment: attrib -h -S C:\*.* i am getting access denid to the files in root of c drive